# Error installing GridDB on Docker for Windows

Tags: griddb

#### GridDB on Docker for Windows

Hi community,

I am trying to install **GridDB** with ***Fixed List mode*** on *Docker (version 20.10.24) for Windows 11, with WSL2 as backend*, following the instructions of the link below:

https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/docker/#dockerhub

However, I get the following error from the container’s log:

> Fixed List mode
> Execution failed. See message logs
> /start-griddb.sh: line 94: exec: griddb: not found

I’m running the following docker run command to instantiate a new container:

```
docker pull griddb/griddb:latest

docker run -d \
--name griddb_server \
--network="host" \
-e GRIDDB_CLUSTER_NAME=myCluster \
-e GRIDDB_PASSWORD=admin \
-e NOTIFICATION_MEMBER=1 \
griddb/griddb:latest
```

Any tip or help to get this solved will be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I could solve the issue using the link:
https://github.com/griddbnet/IoT-Project-Codebase/tree/main/griddb-server

This repo has a fixed start GridDB script.

After download the file then run the following docker commands:

```
docker build .  
docker image tag 5b56e8ac6ccc griddb/griddb  
docker run --name griddb_server --network="host" -e GRIDDB_CLUSTER_NAME=myCluster -e GRIDDB_PASSWORD=admin -e NOTIFICATION_MEMBER=1 griddb/griddb -d
docker logs --follow griddb_server
```